# Android Imageview insidelinear view stops an app

Tags: android, imageview, size, android-linearlayout

Here is my code: main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="@string/image_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/image_date" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"

        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Amd here is my image1.png
http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/s84-27018.jpg

When I try to display this image my application has stopped unfortunately. But other image works fine. So there is some size problem with this image. an anyone please help me to solve this issue? I really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: can you put the code part where you are trying to display image

Comment: that is because of image size.. read this document https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: post your stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Your image is too big to load, you must be getting an outofmemory exception.

you have to scale the image before you display. there is no point in loading 1024 X 1024 image to display on a 42dp X 42dp imageview.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(<picture url>, options);
            myBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(myBitmap, 200, 200);

            imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Image size is very large. Memory issue. Check [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)